# Generalised Binomial Series

Tags: summation, negative-binomial

I am reading an old paper "1971A Generalized Negative Binomial Distribution" by G. C. Jain and P. C. Consul. The paper mainly start from 
$$(1+z)^n=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+x\beta}\binom{n+x\beta}{x}z^x(1+z)^{-\beta x},\quad where \quad |\frac{\beta z}{1+z}|<1.$$

I can understand this. But I cannot understand why (the last two lines of the paper)
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+\beta x}\binom{n+\beta x}{x}=1.$$

Expecting some hints from you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that old paper have an author?

Comment: Yes, G. C. Jain and P. C. Consul.

Comment: Is there any condition on $\beta$?  The last sum is not equal to $1$ when $n$ is a positive integer and $\beta:=0$ (that is, the sum $\sum\limits_{x=0}^n\,\dfrac{n}{n+\beta\,x}\,\displaystyle \binom{n+\beta\,x}{x}$ equals $2^n$ when $\beta:=0$).

Comment: Which equation number as in the paper is the equation in your question?  I see (2.2) is the first equation in your question, what about your second equation?  [This](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0121056) is the paper, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this result provided by the paper is wrong. Simplify run the numerical calculation in any mathematical software will show this is not a probability distribution function at all.

The range of $\beta$, $\beta=0$ or $\beta \geq 1$, could be found in "1980The Generalized Negative Binomial Distribution and its Characterization by ZeroRegression". There are several subsequent papers pointing out the parameter setting in 1971 G. C. Jain and P. C. Consul is not correct.

Let me know if you have other comments.